# Does this vs Is this (grammar)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Can someone explain to me the grammatical rule for these examples:

1. ***Does this*** belong to you? - correct
2. ***Is this*** belongs to you? - wrong

and

1. ***Does this*** mean I am right? - correct
2. **Is it** mean I am right? - wrong

Why can't I use ***Is it***?

Comment: (I assume you mean "Does this belong to you?"  You can't use _is_ because _do_ is the auxiliary verb we use when forming questions. From the Cambridge Grammar website: _Do is one of three auxiliary verbs in English: be, do, have. We use do to make negatives (do + not), to make question forms, and to make the verb more emphatic._

Comment: Would you say “This is belong to you” or “This is mean I am right”?

Answer (score 1):

"Does this ..." refers to some action the subject performs. Like "Does this car run well?" By "action" here I just mean "there's a verb following, not necessarily that something is running or jumping. Like, "Does this food taste good?"

"Is this ..." refers to identity. "Is this the book you asked for?" or "Is this your girlfriend?"

"Is this ..." is also used when asking if an adjective applies. Like, "Is this food good?" or "Is this man rude?"

In your examples, you are not asking for identity but an "action". You could ask, "Is this the right answer?" But you do not say, "Is this answer sound right?" but rather "Does this answer sound right?"

Let me clarify that "identity" is not necessarily unique. You could say, "Is this a good book?" You're not asking if it's the only good book in the history of the world, just if it's "a" good book.

Answer (score 0):

A question (and a negative statement) requires an auxiliary before the subject. If there is already an auxiliary (eg *have*, *are*, *should*) then it comes before the subject:

> *Have you* seen it? (<- You have seen it)

> *Are they* at home?

> *Should I* press the button?

If there is not already an auxiliary, then for all verbs other than *be* and (for some speakers) *have*, the auxiliary *do* is inserted before the subject:

> *Do they* speak English? (<- They speak English)

> *Does this* belong to you? (<- This belongs to you)

The only auxiliary inserted in this way is *do* (*does*, *don't*, *doesn't*, *did*, *didn't*). All other auxiliaries (such as *is*) are used only if they would be there in the corresponding statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simple present tense

Affirmative: I play. You play. We play. They play. The boys play. He play**s**. She play**s**. The boy play**s**. (-s for the third person singular)

Negative: I *do not* play. You *do not* play. We *do not* play. They *do not* play. The boys *do not* play. He *do**es** not* play. She *do**es** not* play. The boy *do**es** not* play.

Question: *Do* I play? *Do* you play? *Do* we play? *Do* they play? *Do* the boys play? *Do**es*** he play? *Do**es*** she play? *Do**es*** the boy play?

Affirmative: This belong**s** to you. (-s for the third person singular)

Negative: This **does not** belong to you

Question: **Does** this belong to you?

Affirmative: This mean**s** (-s for the third person singular)

Negative: This **does not** mean.

Question: **Does** this mean?